# Error "We don't have as many..." not showing up

Tags: magento2

I have a strange problem in my Magento installation.
The classic message "We don't have as many "xxxx" as you requested." is not showing. The page reload and no message showing.
Ideas?

Comment: no, my question is different...

Comment: All caches is flushed? You used the default theme?

Comment: - caches flushed
- default theme and custom theme switch test done

Comment: i found that was a plugin causing this issue.

Comment: which plugin @goplastic